# Winter 21 Release and API Version availability

Tags: api, pre-release, winter21

Is API Version 50.0 for Winter '21 release available? I am in a pre-release developer edition org and I can't see the version 50.0

Comment: How are you determining the version of API available in your org

Comment: Just spun up a pre-release org and it seems to have v50.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what API version is available in an org, go to any Apex class and click the `Edit` button.
Under `Version Settings`, you can choose the latest version from the `Salesforce.com API` picklist. If it doesn't show 50, your org hasn't been updated to the latest prerelease version.

Answer (score 1):

Sign up for pre-release org  [here](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter21/) and API version 50 is available.

[image]

Thanks,